# Error on application start

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, crash

I am very new to Xcode. I followed an example on YouTube but I am getting the following error on launch of the app

```
2014-05-16 20:45:02.378 CoreData[9335:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'Patient''
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01b5a1e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x018d98e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreData                            0x00238a1b +[NSEntityDescription entityForName:inManagedObjectContext:] + 251
    3   CoreData                            0x00004235 -[PatientsTableViewController fetechResultsController] + 213
    4   CoreData                            0x00003bd1 -[PatientsTableViewController viewDidLoad] + 97
    5   UIKit                               0x006b833d -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 696
    6   UIKit                               0x006b85d9 -[UIViewController view] + 35
    7   UIKit                               0x006e3509 -[UINavigationController rotatingSnapshotViewForWindow:] + 52
    8   UIKit                               0x00a2ae3c -[UIClientRotationContext initWithClient:toOrientation:duration:andWindow:] + 420
    9   UIKit                               0x005dfc22 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:isRotating:] + 1495
    10  UIKit                               0x005df646 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 82
    11  UIKit                               0x005df518 -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 117
    12  UIKit                               0x005df5a0 -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:duration:force:] + 67
    13  UIKit                               0x005de63a __57-[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:]_block_invoke + 120
    14  UIKit                               0x005de59c -[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:] + 400
    15  UIKit                               0x005df2f3 -[UIWindow setAutorotates:forceUpdateInterfaceOrientation:] + 870
    16  UIKit                               0x005e28e6 -[UIWindow setDelegate:] + 449
    17  UIKit                               0x006bcb77 -[UIViewController _tryBecomeRootViewControllerInWindow:] + 180
    18  UIKit                               0x005d8474 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 591
    19  UIKit                               0x005d85ef -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 312
    20  UIKit                               0x005d886b -[UIWindow _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 49
    21  UIKit                               0x005e33c8 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 65
    22  UIKit                               0x00593bc0 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 2097
    23  UIKit                               0x00598667 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 824
    24  UIKit                               0x005acf92 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3517
    25  UIKit                               0x005ad555 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
    26  UIKit                               0x0059a250 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 683
    27  GraphicsServices                    0x03a0df02 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
    28  GraphicsServices                    0x03a0da0d PurpleEventCallback + 46
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x01ad5ca5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x01ad59db __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x01b0068c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x01aff9d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x01aff7eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    34  UIKit                               0x00597d9c -[UIApplication _run] + 840
    35  UIKit                               0x00599f9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    36  CoreData                            0x00002efd main + 141
    37  libdyld.dylib                       0x021a1701 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

This is how I am defining the function but I cant see anywhere its getting nill from?

```
-(NSFetchedResultsController*)fetechResultsController{

if (_fetechResultsController !=nil) {
    return  _fetechResultsController;
}
NSFetchRequest  *fetchRequest=[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSManagedObjectContext *context =[self managedObjectContext];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Patient" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"patientLastName" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortdescriptors = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortdescriptors;

_fetechResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

_fetechResultsController.delegate   =self;

return _fetechResultsController;

}
```

Comment: You'll need to post the full error message

Comment: See http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: Hint for the future, if you read what the error message says you will get lots and lots of clues where to start looking in your code, for example "for entity name 'Patient", "[PatientsTableViewController fetechResultsController]", etc. Look at how you are calling entityForName and if Patient is nil and things like that

Comment: @MartinH I have included where I am defining the entityforname as you can see their is no nill

Comment: The stack trace tells you that the error happened in your `[PatientsTableViewController fetechResultsController]` method, and it tells you what the error is. If you look at that method while considering the error you might figure it out. If not, it would help to add the code from that method to your question.

Comment: @David put a breakpoint on the first line inside fetechResultsController. Now run your app and use the debugger and step over each line one by one. Then you will know exactly which line is causing the problem. Then run it again and stop before that line, then you can look at the values of the variables used in line in Xcode to see if they are as expected. It is perhaps the case that context is nil or entity is nil.

Comment: After you call [self managedObjectContext], what is the value it returns?